# Javascript querySelectorAll on :visible elements is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to target some classes on my web page which are visible in the DOM, but for some reason I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.form-control:visible' is not a valid selector.

Surely this **is** valid, what am I missing?

My HTML:

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
```

My JS:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control:visible')

for (const [index, input] of inputs.entries()) {
    console.log(input)
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How is the visibility controlled on those elements? By class, inline style or??

Comment: Inputs are always shown, the surrounding elements are shown/hidden with a combination of `style` and classes, there's over 100 inputs and 20+ steps in my actual form - the attached is simply a small reproduction, in reality, we're talking about a large-scale 2,000+ line HTML project. So need the simplest solution possible at identifying the visibility of an input (I have inputs, selects and radio groups that will all need the same solution applied to)

Comment: There's a variety of approaches for managing steps in large forms. I'm assuming a lot of this involves hiding whole sections for which using fieldsets can be very helpful A sample of what you need to accomplish would help

Comment: So what makes them not visible? You are going to have to key off that or you are going to have to select them all and use filter()

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid, there is no `:visible` pseudo-class listed in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/).

jQuery supports a [`:visible` selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), but it is non-standard and you aren't using jQuery.

The jQuery documentation says:

> Because :visible is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :visible cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :visible to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":visible").

Answer (score -2):

Hy!
There is no such ":visible" selector in JavaScript.
**":visible"** is a selector of jQuery which is used to create opacity 0 and 1 or shoe and hide.
Thanks

Comment: `:visible` does not create opacity. First statement is simply not correct